# Change Order of Literal Entries in R# Snippet Templates

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper-8.0

So the R# template for foreach looks like this:

```
foreach ($TYPE$ $VARIABLE$ in $COLLECTION$)
{
  $END$
}
```

The problem is that it jumps me to enter $COLLECTION$, then $TYPE$, then $VARIABLE$, but my mental process is $TYPE$, $VARIABLE$, $COLLECTION$, and the ordering is tripping me up all the time. Is there a way to change the order in which these get entered? I didn't see anything in the template specifying order.

**EDIT**

Of course, I found the answer as soon as posed the question. Edit the template from Template Explorer and change the order of the variables on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the template from Template Explorer and change the order of the variables on the right.